# Find entry in table with a column with same value

Tags: mysql

The title is a bit wrong, i can explain better here.
Say i have a MySQL table like this:

mysql> select * from people;

```
+------+---------------+
| name | number        |
+------+---------------+
| John |        100000 |
| Alex |        200000 |
| Tim  |        500000 |
| Alice|        100000 |
| Peter|        500000 |
+------+---------------+
```

And now i want a query which returns the names of the people who have the same number, ie, for this table i would a query which would return John and Alice (they have the same number, 100000) and Tim and Peter (the same number 500000)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try self join as below:

```
SELECT p1.name
FROM people p1 INNER JOIN people p2
ON p1.number = p2.number
WHERE p1.name != p2.name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by aggregating on the number column and using `group_concat()`.  A `having` clause selects only cases where there is more than one name:

```
select number, group_concat(name) as names
from table t
group by number
having count(*) > 1;
```